# Bean Validation - using no parameter methods

Tags: ejb-3.0, bean-validation

I have following interface

```
@Local
public interface MyBeanLocal {
  @ValidUser
  int create(User user);
  String getCurrentUser();
}
```

and implementation:

```
@Stateless
@MethodValidated
public class MyBean implements MyBeanLocal {

   public int create(User user) {
      String currentUser = getCurrentUser();
      user.setCreatedBy(currentUser);  
   }

   public String getCurrentUser() {
      return "test";  
   }

}
```

When I call create I receive following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HV000116: The method parameter array cannot not be null.
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Contracts.assertNotNull(Contracts.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:196)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Is it possible to disable validation on method getCurrentUser?

Comment: Is the `@ValidUser` constraint a cross-parameter constraint or a return value constraint? I'd assume the former, but I'm wondering why you don't make it a simple constraint and put it to the parameter itself?

Comment: This is only simple example and of course I could use constraint on method parameter. But I ask for my question because I would like to use cross-parameter validation. I've just found an answer for my question in Bean Validation specification - `"It is not legal to declare a cross-parameter constraint on a method or constructor which has no parameters. A ConstraintDeclarationException is raised in this case."`